# Compiler Error Message: CS1513

Tags: asp.net

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message:

> CS1513: } expected

Source Error:

```
Line 132:    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 133:    {
Line 134:       string url = "gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/fhWaJi1Hsfo/comments";
Line 135:       string ReadTextFromUrl(string url) 
Line 136:       {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have one method embedded inside of another.  You need to separate the methods, and then call it appropriately:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/fhWaJi1Hsfo/comments";
    string result = ReadTextFromUrl(url);
}

string ReadTextFromUrl(string url) 
{
    // code here
}
```